# Ubuntu 14.04.3 Update to Vivid HW enablement stack - still getting updates to old kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, update-manager

Recently i installed the Vivid Hardware enablement stack from the ubuntu wiki (kernel 3.19, xorg 1.17)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

and the update happened without problems...

However after going through the packages to-be-upgraded by the update manager, i saw that it included kernel updates to the old 3.13 kernel..!!

Is that normal? Can it potentially screw up my system? I am unwilling to update, until i know for certain that nothing breaks and keep the 3.19 kernel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop updates of 3.13 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 you need to remove meta-packages. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Updates of 3.13 kernel can not do any harm. But there is no real need to keep them upgrading.

For kernels 3.19 you have other meta-packages installed: `linux-image-generic-lts-vivid` and `linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid`.

Comment: problem: i removed them, but i still get updates to the 3.13 kernel.Do i have to remove ALL 3.13 kernels??